# Migrate to androidx recently and I have discovered a layout problem with alertdialog

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, androidx

When i use an AlertDialog import with import `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`;
In the title we observe an unwanted linearLayout.

When I change `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`; to
`import android.app.AlertDialog`;
The problem disappears.

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;


  AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
        } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        }
builder .setMessage(json)
                    .setTitle("Info")
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
```

With androidx :

[image: Androix import issue]

Without but expected :

[image: without androidx but expected]

thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be working fine with androidx

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.label_update_available))
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.label_download_content))
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, (dialog, which) -> {
                HandleNotifications.setDownloadReminder(this, DownloadReceiver.class);
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
            .show();
```

Comment: it seems to be linked to android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert

Comment: import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog; This was the import used above .Haven't used this theme .